# Provide custom UUID to spark job through airflow DataprocSubmitJobOperator

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, airflow

I want to give a custom job id to the spark jobs submitted through Airflow DataprocSubmitJobOperator on Google cloud.

Through API we can do that using --id param, any idea how can we give the same through this operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify job id in the "reference" field

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs#jobreference

Comment: well this is stange. I tried the same thing yesterday and it didn't work! However, its somehow working today! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to give a custom job id by specifying the task_id in the configuration of DataprocSubmitJobOperator. You can find more about it in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#submit-a-job-to-a-cluster).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried with task_id already and it is not same as job id.